# Javascript Callback when variable is set to X

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have an issue I can't seem to wrap my head around. I'm wanting to write a generic javascript function that will accept a variable and a callback, and continue to execute until that variable is something other than false.

For example, the variable SpeedFeed.user.sid is false until something else happens in the code, but I don't want to execute a particular callback until it has been set.

The call:

```
SpeedFeed.helper_ready(SpeedFeed.user.sid, function(){
  alert(SpeedFeed.user.sid);
  // Run function that requires sid to be set.
});
```

The function:

```
helper_ready: function(vtrue, callback){
  if(vtrue != false){
    callback();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){
       SpeedFeed.helper_ready(vtrue, callback);
    }, SpeedFeed.apiCheckTime);
  }
}
```

The issue I've narrowed it down to appears to be that because in the setTimeout I call vtrue instead of the actual SpeedFeed.user.sid, it's going to be set to false always. I realize I could write a specific function for each time that just evaluates the SpeedFeed.user.sid, but I'd like to have a generic method that I could use throughout the application.

Thanks for any insight :)

Comment: Is `SpeedFeed.user.sid` a function, or not? I assumed it was because you wrote *"I call vtrue instead of the actual SpeedFeed.user.sid"*. Because you're calling it, I assume it is a function. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the current value of `vtrue` to `setTimeout` which then repeats the process so the parameter `vtrue` is always the same (`vtrue` is immutable).

Instead of writing a callback-like function that checks whenever a particular value is true, why not make setter and getter functions that can invoke `callback()` or just call `callback()` directly whenever `vtrue` would be `true`? The code will be much easier to follow this way and you will not need hacks such as `setTimeout` looping.

There are multiple solutions to this problem that do not require a callback.  One conventional approach would be to use [setters and getters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) instead of assignments.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Trey answer, since I was also thinking of `setter` and `getter`. In addition to set and get functionality I would suggest to add something like `registerListener` and `unregisterListener` which will register listeners to follow the state of your variable. And then each time getter is called iterate over all listeners and tell them about updated value, or just pass this value to them.

Answer (score 0):

Pass to helper_ready three parameters:
source_object, object`s_property, callback

and then check status of object`s property.
in your case it will be

```
SpeedFeed.helper_ready(SpeedFeed.user, "sid", function(){
  alert(SpeedFeed.user.sid);
  // Run function that requires sid to be set.
});
```

for global property:

```
SpeedFeed.helper_ready(window, "sid", function(){
  alert(windwo.sid);
  // Run function that requires sid to be set.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timeout use `setInterval`. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920986/jquery-empty-and-memory/2922739#2922739). It is similar to what you're trying to do.