# jqGrid memory leak on reloadGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I haven't been able to find a solution to a memory leak in Internet Explorer 8 (haven't tried any other).

The leak is caused by calling [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start)'s `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");` method.

I tried `deepempty: true` but that did not work. I also tried to call `clearGridData`, but to no avail :(

I use the latest 3.8.2 version of jqGrid and load JSON data from the server.

Comment: You should post the jqGrid definition (full JavaScript code) which one can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: if you think my answer satisfy your question, could you, please, consider closing it? Thanks.

Comment: what jQuery version are you using? Someone had a similar issue and it seems that jQuery 1.5 has solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064034/memory-leak-when-using-jquery-ui-tabs-ver-1-8-9/5064224#5064224

Comment: Hi LeftyX, I am using 1.4.4, and sure, I will close the issue as I test your suggestion with 1.5, might take me a day or two (too much work piled up)

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try my app with jQuery 1.5 but it seems that the issue has been fixed. I read that jqGrid has some issues with jQuery 1.5 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");` in different occasions and tested it with IE8 and I've never had any trouble.
How many rows are you loading?
Could you provide some code?

Comment: Hi, I think it's useless to post any code due to a simple reason: if you go to [TRIRAND SITE](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and open menu item Loading Data -> JSON Data, then try to refresh the grid manually and observe the iexplore.exe memory behavior, it increases with every refresh :( Now imagine refreshing the grid every 5 seconds on an intranet application :)

Comment: Yes, but, why would you refresh your grid every 5 seconds? Couldn't you just POST/GET (with jQuery) on a page which tells you if the data has changed. If there are changes you simply reload the grid.

Comment: Anyway, I had a similar issue with jquery and IE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920986/jquery-empty-and-memory and I didn't find a real solution. There's a ticket open too: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6242 I reckon the problem sits in jQuery not in jqGrid. I would avoid reloading the grid every 5secs. I ended up refresh my page every x cycles.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing, reloading every 5 seconds and refreshing after 100 reloads. However, I like your idea on conditional reload, really smooth solution :) And, thanks for the ticket, I will surely follow it. Another thing I noticed is that after Ajax.BeginForm (MVC2 ASP.NET) is complete, the content of the element is replaced, however the memory leak is also there so had to clear the element's html :(

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence "after Ajax.BeginForm (MVC2 ASP.NET) is complete, the content of the element is replaced"

Comment: Well, one will usually write something similar: `using (Ajax.BeginForm(
         "GenerateReport"
       , "Report"
       , new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "waitImageDiv", UpdateTargetId = "mainReportForm", OnSuccess = "reportFunctions.Initialize" }
       , new { id = "mainReportForm" }))
   { ` Now, the controller returns the PartialView which fills in the `UpdatetargetId`. One would expect no memory leaks but...it leaks :(

Comment: I am sorry, I can't help you on that.I don't use (and don't want to) Microsoft Ajax scripts.I tend to do everything with jQuery.I don't particularly trust MS on that :-s

Comment: jQuery 1.5 seems to have slowed down the leak considerably, however the advent is still there, i.e. there's a minor leak. I pumped the data every 50 ms and it seems to be stale for awhile and then it increases a memory usage by couple of 100 KBs. Anyway, the answer is partially valid but I decided to accept it.