# Memory Leak When Using jQuery UI Tabs (ver 1.8.9)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, memory-leaks

I'm getting a memory leak when using the jQuery 1.8.9 UI tabs, and am a little baffled as to what might be causing it. The issue only seems to present in IE. I'm using IE8, (haven't tested in on 7 or 6). Firefox and Chrome are ok.

The tabs are initialised like so:

```
$("#tabContent").tabs({ cache: false, ajaxOptions: { cache: false} });
$("#tabContent").bind('tabsselect', tabSelected);
$("#tabContent").bind('tabsload', tabLoaded);

$("#tabContent").tabs("url", 0, "SomePage.aspx?id=1" + "&project=" + projectName);
$("#tabContent").tabs("url", 1, "SomePage.aspx?id=2" + "&project=" + projectName);
$("#tabContent").tabs("url", 2, "SomePage.aspx?id=3" + "&project=" + projectName);
$("#tabContent").tabs("url", 3, "SomePage.aspx?id=4" + "&project=" + projectName);
```

The page 'SomePage' has a list with a status column, which I need to check for update. I'm polling this every 5000 milliseconds (using [this timeout plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/)):

```
$.doTimeout('tabDisplay', 5000, function() {
    $("#tabContent").tabs("load", $("#tabContent").tabs('option', 'selected'));
    return true;
});
```

And sure, enough every 5 seconds the memory usage climbs (in direct proportion to the size of the list on that tab).

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really help with this but I can tell you I've struggled quite a lot for the same [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920986/jquery-empty-and-memory)
The other day someone else had another problem with [IE8 and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015098/jqgrid-memory-leak-on-reloadgrid/5015501#5015501) .
I don't think it is related to jQuery UI but I reckon has more to do with jQuery and IE8:

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/10/08/jquery-ajax-memory-leak-in-ie8#fn0
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6242

I had founds loads of people struggling for the same problems but no real solution.

PS: in all these situation there's a polling. It seems that jQuery doesn't dispose the resources.
I am referring to jQuery 1.4.x

Comment: Thanks lefty. In the end I updated to jQuery 1.5 and the issue disappeared. (1.4.4. didn't seem to solve the issue)

Comment: Great! I've never had the chance to update my app cause I've used another workaround.I am glad to know that the issue has been fixed ... finally.